# Please help me with Android Notepad tutorial

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to resolve an issue for a couple hours now, and can't seem to find a solution in the archives. I'm hoping some generous coder will help out a noob here.

I've been following the steps outlined in the Notepad tutorial, specifically "Notepadv1" located at this URL: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

Even after confirming my code with that of the solution files, I am still seeing these errors.

[image: asd]

Please help me figure out what I've done wrong so I can move to the next step in the training.

I'm working with Eclipse.

Comment: Did you add the relevant XMLs in the xml files? You have missing resources in your projects, judging from the first 3 errors.

Edit: Your `fillData()` method is not present.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that Step 8, part 6 of your [guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html), is not really clear. It says:

> Finally, call a new method fillData(), which will get the data and
>   populate the ListView using the helper — we haven't defined this
>   method yet.

What they mean here, is to just define a method that does nothing, and they will fill-in the body later (see below). You can define it as follows:

```
private void fillData(){}
```

To actually populate it see step 12 in your [guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html):
Define the **fillData()** method, which should look like:

```
private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

obviously you don't have a `fillData()` method in your activity.